# Almacenar una clase en una variable

Tags: c#

Quisiera almacenar una Clase en una variable, para poder usar esa variable sea la clase que este almacenando. Había pensado una variable de tipo object

```
if (nameForm == "Cliente")
        {
            Cliente _cliente = new Cliente();
            var sourceType = _cliente.GetType();
            var tipoEntidad = sourceType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            PropertyInfo[] property = tipoEntidad.GetProperties();
```

No nececito instanciar la clase, necesito la clase en si.
¿Como puedo almacenar una clase en una variable?

Comment: la verdad es que no se entiende lo que buscas, quieres tener la definicion de la clase o solo el nombre ? que es eso de tener la clase en si?

Comment: Necesito tener el objeto

Comment: que es tener el objeto? si dices que no quiere instanciarlo, un objeto se obtiene cuando haces el "new" de la clase

Comment: Hola Leandro, no me he explicado bien, nececito tener la clase para poder recorrer sus propiedades con reflection, pero en el código que implemento para eso necesito que sea la clase que llegue, lo intente con generic pero tuve el problema que no dejaba trabajar al diseñador del formulario por eso opbte por enviarle la clase directamente.

Comment: Pero quiero que el método me sirba para todas las clases que le envie, es por eso que quería hacerlo con generic pero me da problemas, hay alguna manera de almacenar las clase ne un typeof(myClase) pero esa myClase puede ser cualquiera que llegue ahí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declara tu variable como [`System.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-gt/library/system.type.aspx), que es la base de la reflexión.

así:

```
Type unaClase;
//obtener la clase de una variable
unaClase = myVariable.GetType();
Type otraClase;
//asignar directamente una clase
otraClase = typeof(MiClase);
```

Si tuvieras que instanciar la clase, puedes valerte de [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-gt/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

```
UserControl tmp = (UserControl) Activator.CreateInstance(unaClase);
```

[edit]: He editado la respuesta para añadir un ejemplo de asignación directa.

Comment: Hola myVariable seria la Clase, pero necesito alojar la clase en una variable pero no se de que tipo he probado con object y no funciona, claro que una vez que la tenga le puedo porner GetType, pero antes de ese paso nesecito alojar la Clase en algo.

Comment: En si si nececito instanciar la clase, por que lo que deseo es mapear las propiedades de una clase con el valores que me traen los controles de mi formulario(windows forms)

Comment: puse el ejemplo de GetType como eso, un ejemplo de cómo inicializar la variable. No importa como la obtengas, puedes asignar directamente la clase si fuera el caso. No tienes que obtenerla con GetType, y eso no cambia el hecho de que una variable será de tipo `Type` es la que puede contener una clase.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para añadir un ejemplo de asignación directa con una hipotética clase `MiClase`

Comment: Gracias, me conviene ponerla directamente `var unaClase = typeof (Cliente);` pero cuando hago esto `var tipoEntidad = unaClase.GenericTypeArguments[0]` me da error el indice fuera de rango.